# Fail to show Activity Bar in vscode 2019 on Windows10

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a problem of showing "Activity Bar" in my vscode 2019.

I click view and "appearance isn't on the drop down menu as an option".Also, ctrl + shift + p does nothing and searching "activity bar" doesn't help.

I installed both 2017 and 2019 in my windows.The appearance of 2019 just look like 2017. How I can solve this problem.

Thanks for your help!
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: That's a screenshot of Visual Studio IDE, not "Visual Studio Code". (I'll admit I don't recognize the icon though - VS Code does have a blue icon, but your IDE looks identical to VS2019 which normally has a purple icon, but yours is blue - do you have a custom theme or extension installed that changes the icon?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I I have figured it out. Thanks a lot!